# Size of an array initialized as a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a `struct foo` of which I have to get the length of an array `bar` inside of `foo`'s constructor.

```
struct foo {
    int *bar_;
    foo(int *bar) : bar_(bar) {
        int size = // I need the length of "bar" = 4 here
    }
};

int main() {
    foo f({3, 16, 56, 4});
    return 0;
}
```

How do I do it?

Comment: `bar` is not an array, but an `int` pointer. The compiler will know nothing else. You need to pass the size as an extra parameter. Better yet, use `std::vector`...

Comment: [good explanation](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/11/28/cpp-passing-c-style-array-with-size-information-to-function/)

Comment: @JHBonarius I need this for a neural network project, I tried to use a std::vector but it was too slow for me, so I tried to use pointers to arrays. Can't I do something like iterate through array pointer bar is pointing too and increment the ```length``` every time?

Comment: You can use `std::array` for fixed size arrays that are stored on the stack. If you need variable size arrays stored on the heap and `std::vector` is too slow for you, you have a bigger problem anyhow.

Comment: @qubix00n *I tried to use a std::vector but it was too slow for me* -- Which more often than not means you were timing a "debug" build, not an optimized release build, or you were not using `vector` properly.  A `vector` is doing nothing different than your attempts of using `new[]` and pointers, only safer, and more than likely, more efficiently.

Comment: Just pass in the size as an argument: `foo f(4, {3, 16, 56, 4});` to `foo(size_t size, int *bar)`